# regex expression to find 10 or 100,1000...doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, regex, numbers, match

I create the regex /(10?|10{2,})/g to find 1,10 or 100,1000... but the code below doesn't return the expected result. I don't know where I went wrong, please help me!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Regular Expressions</h2>

<p>Do a global search for a "1", followed by zero or one "0" characters:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
let text = "1, 10, 100 or 1000?";
let result = text.match(/(10?|10{2,})/g);
//should return 1,10,100,1000 but instead return 1,10,10,10
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `10?` will match all the `1`, `10`, `100`, `1000` in your string, and since that is the first element in the alternation, the regex engine stops when it matches (and so your longest match is `10`). You could solve that by swapping the alternation around so that the longest match is first:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Regular Expressions</h2>

<p>Do a global search for a "1", followed by zero or one "0" characters:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
let text = "1, 10, 100 or 1000?";
let result = text.match(/10{2,}|10?/g);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But better yet, just simplify the regex to `10*` (`1` followed by 0 or more `0`s):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Regular Expressions</h2>

<p>Do a global search for a "1", followed by zero or one "0" characters:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
let text = "1, 10, 100 or 1000?";
let result = text.match(/10*/g);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Note that these regexes will also match `21`, `12` or `5107`. If you don't want to do that, add a `\b` (word boundary) at each end of the regex. See below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Regular Expressions</h2>

<p>Do a global search for a "1", followed by zero or one "0" characters:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
let text = "1, 10, 100 or 1000? But what about 12, 21 and 5107?";
let result = text.match(/\b10*\b/g);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Note also that you don't need a capturing group `(...)` in your regex as you are only interested in the whole match.

Comment: @LinhChi no worries, I hope it was useful. Please see my edit, which talks about not matching a `1` in the middle of another number.

Answer (score 1):

I will add.

Search substrings:

```js
let text = "1, 10, 100 or 1000 (3100, 10000, 1000000)?";
let result = text.match(/10{1,3}/g);
```

Output:

```
10,100,1000,100,1000,1000
```

Search words only on pattern:

```js
let text = "1, 10, 100 or 1000 (3100, 10000, 1000000)?";
let result = text.match(/\b10{1,3}\b/g);
```

Output:

```
10,100,1000
```

Search words only on pattern 1 and more zeroes:

```js
let text = "1, 10, 100 or 1000 (3100, 10000, 1000000)?";
let result = text.match(/\b10{1,}\b/g);
```

Output:

```
10,100,1000,10000,1000000
```

Find words ending in a pattern of 1 or more zeros:

```js
let text = "1, 10, 100 or 1000 (3100, 10000, 1000000)?";
let result = text.match(/\b\w*10{1,}\b/g);
```

Output:

```
10,100,1000,3100,10000,1000000
```

Finds words ending only in a pattern of 1 or more zeros:

```js
let text = "1, 10, 100 or 1000 (3100, 10000, 1000000)?";
let result = text.match(/\b\w+10{1,}\b/g);
```

Output:

```
3100
```